# React Native: JSON value '<null>' of type NSNULL cannot be converted to a valid URL

Tags: android, iphone, reactjs, firebase, react-native

For the app that I am currently working on, I am using the following snippets of code to access the device photo gallery to then replace a default image displayed on the screen. I have the default value set to null which should be fine? This works fine on `Android` however I receive this error on iPhone devices.

Any ideas on how to fix it? (Avatar is what the image is)

```
state = {
user: {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  //Fix it!
  //Works on Android for some reason? But fix the emulator error
  avatar: null
},
errorMessage: null
```

};

```
handlePickAvatar = async () => {
UserPermissions.getCameraPermission()

let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3]
})

if(!result.cancelled){
  this.setState({user: { ...this.state.user, avatar: result.uri} });
}
```

};

```
<View style={{position: "absolute", top: 45, alignItems: "center", width: "100%"}}>

      <Text style={styles.greeting}>{'Hello!\nSign up to get started.'}</Text>

      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.avatarPlaceholder} onPress={this.handlePickAvatar}>
        <Image source={{uri:this.state.user.avatar}} style={styles.avatar}/>
        <Ionicons 
        name="ios-add" 
        size={40} 
        color="#00d589" 
        style={{marginTop:6, marginLeft:2}}>
        </Ionicons>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
```

I only seem to receive the **JSON value  of type NSNULL cannot be converted to a valid URL** error on the iPhone emulator due to the state that "avatar" is set to null. I followed this Youtube tutorial exactly up to 4:30 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UNFDILca9M8

Is there something I am missing? I have all the packages installed and can't see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by running a simple null check statement within the Image tag itself.